# BASH - How to delete a line which contains 2nd occurrence of a pattern string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Consider the below configuration file and it has two instances of `alt_names`. Here, I want to delete a line with second occurrence of a pattern `alt_names`.

```
.
.
[ server ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
.
.

[ alt_names ]
```

I tried `sed` command but it deletes all the lines with the pattern occurrence. I used the below command to do so,

```
#sed '/alt_names/{2,$d}' inputfile
```

Can some shed lights on whats gone wrong the usage of `sed` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will delete the second line which contains `alt_names`. Counter `c` will increase with each line having the pattern matched.

```
awk '/alt_names/{c++;if(c==2)gsub(/^.*$/,"")}1'
.
[ server ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
.
.
```

To modify and save:

```
awk '/alt_names/{c++;if(c==2)gsub(/^.*$/,"")}1' inputfile >inputfile.tmp && mv inputfile.tmp inputfile
```

Comment: How to modify the file itself and save.

Comment: check update in answer

Comment: I see that, still we need to use temp file here. I though there should be something similar to what `sed` has like `sed -i <command> filename`

Comment: check the dups marked by Inian, it contains some better alternatives.